# Can I align a button's label with its layout margins?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit

One way to left-align a `UIButton`'s title is to set the `contentHorizontalAlignment` to `.left` (or `.leading`). But this places the title flush with the left edge of the button with no margin. A common way to add some margin is to set the `contentEdgeInstets`.

But my button extends from once edge of the screen to the other, so I would like the left and right margins to honor the `layoutMargins`. These margins might change as the view is resized or the device is rotated.

[image]

Is there a way to set the button's insets to observe these margins? Or should I create a button from a custom view where I can use my own label and anchor it to the `layoutMarginsGuide`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can manually set the margin of the button using titleEdgeInsets to match the inset of the Cancel Button.

Have a look at the following, the two buttons are exactly the same aside from the origin.y and the titleEdgeInsets:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
view.backgroundColor = .white

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 200, height: 80))
button.setTitle("Some really long title", for: .normal)
button.backgroundColor = .red
button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)

let button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 160, width: 200, height: 80))
button2.setTitle("Some really long title", for: .normal)
button2.backgroundColor = .red
button2.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
button2.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)


view.addSubview(button)
view.addSubview(button2)
```

It gives the following result:

[image: Button Test]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yep, except hardcoding those insets means they won't respond to rotations and re-sizes which update the margins.

Comment: [How about trying something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8274432/10058854) to determine the inset amounts?

Comment: Thanks, but I think if I have to monitor layout changes to update the insets I'd rather add my own label and just pin it to the `layoutMarginsGuide` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A subclassed button may work for you...

```
class RespectSuperviewMarginButton: UIButton {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if let sv = superview {
            contentEdgeInsets.left = sv.layoutMargins.left
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yep, looking that way. This is simpler than what I had in mind though, thanks. Though I might just add my own label and pin it to the button's layout margins rather than look 'up' through the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

My current best answer is: no, this is not possible without subclassing.

The subclass implementation I am currently using is simple enough:

```
class LayoutMarginRespectingButton: UIButton {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        contentEdgeInsets = layoutMargins
    }
}
```